# Is every finite subgroup the integer points of a linear algebraic group?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

Cross Posting this from MSE since it's been there for almost a month and it got a couple upvotes but no answers. MSE link [Is every finite subgroup the integer points of a linear algebraic group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375025/is-every-finite-subgroup-the-integer-points-of-a-linear-algebraic-group)

Let $ K $ be a compact connected Lie group. For every finite subgroup $ \Gamma $ of $ K $ does there exist a linear algebraic group $ G $ such that the integer points are
$$
G_\mathbb{Z} \cong \Gamma 
$$
and the real points are
$$
G_\mathbb{R} \cong K.
$$

I'm interested in this because sometimes the integer points are cool like
$$
\operatorname{SO}_3(\mathbb{Z}) \cong S_4.
$$

EDIT: Here is an attempt to clarify what I am looking for.

Consider 3 by 3 matrices with complex entries. For a $ 3 \times 3 $ complex matrix the conditions
$$
I=MM^T
$$
and
$$
det(M)=1
$$
are polynomial in the entries of $ M $. The polynomials defining these conditions all have integer coefficients. The subset of matrices that satisfy these two constraints is the Lie group $ SO_3(\mathbb{C}) $. Now if we restrict the entries to be real then we get exactly the group $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ which is a compact connected Lie group. Finally, if we restrict the entries to be integers we get $ SO_3(\mathbb{Z}) $ which is a finite group with 24 elements isomorphic to the symmetric group $ S_4 $.

So what I was really interested in was the idea that for any compact connected lie group $ K $ and finite subgroup $ \Gamma $ we can find a (finite collection of integer coefficient) polynomial constraints on the entries of a square matrix such that the complex matrices satisfying those constraints form a Lie group, the matrices satisfying those constraints and having real entries form a compact connected Lie group, and finally the matrices satisfying those constraints and having integer entries form a finite group isomorphic to $ \Gamma $.

Comment: A problem is that $G_\mathbf{Z}$ is not well-defined for a linear algebraic group. For $\mathrm{SO}_3$, etc, this is well-defined, because these are embedded subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n$.

Comment: I would highly doubt one can get the e.g. icosahedral subgroup of $SO(3)$ this way. But maybe I’m misunderstanding the question…

Comment: You're not misunderstanding the question Sam that's actually the finite subgroup I'm most interested in I've even specifically asked in the past if there is a form of $ SO_3 $ with icosahedral as the group of integer points https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4287901/icosahedral-form-of-mathrmso-3-mathbbr

Comment: For the meaning of $G_{\mathbb Z}$, doubtless the question is "does there exist a connected, [reductive?] linear algebraic group $G$ over $\mathbb Z$ such that …", and then $G_{\mathbb Z}$ and $G_{\mathbb R}$ are both well defined. \\ Can you obviously always do this for $\Gamma = 1$? \\ Could you link to the MSE question?  I can't find it.

Comment: @LSpice really "doubtless"? "linear algebraic group over $\mathbf{Z}$" is a quite subtle notion, more appropriately called group scheme over $\mathbf{Z}$, involving all issues of reduction in small characteristic... it sounds more reasonable to assume that it means a $\mathbf{Q}$-subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n$.

Comment: @YCor But then $G(\mathbb Z)$ is not well-defined (as you note). So we must be working with some kind of group scheme $G$ over $\mathbb Z$ whose generic fiber $G_{\mathbb Q}$ is a reductive algebraic group satisfying $G_{\mathbb Q}(\mathbb R) = K$. What conditions to put on finite primes is indeed not obvious but from my reading that's the only thing that's unclear.

Comment: @WillSawin For a Zariski-closed subgroup $G$ of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$, $G(\mathbf{Z})$ is well-defined as $G\cap \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\newcommand\Q{{\mathbb Q}}$@YCor, but, by equipping your $\mathbb Q$-group $G_\Q$ with a faithful representation into $\GL_{n, \Q}$, regarded as $(\GL_{n, \mathbb Z})_\Q$, you've exhibited a $\mathbb Z$-form $G$ of it, namely, just as you say, $A \mapsto G_\Q(A \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \Q) \cap \operatorname{GL}_n(A)$ for every $\mathbb Z$-algebra $A$.  I guess your point is that this might not be (or at least isn't obviously) representable?  I think the notion of group scheme itself is otherwise rather unsubtle—it's smoothness and reductivity that are subtle!

Comment: @LSpice yes of course. But I mean all this needs no knowledge of group schemes over rings to be defined (the OP doesn't seem familiar with this language, let alone the inherent difficulties of dealing with such general group schemes). So I'd understand the question as whether there is $n$ and a continuous representation $f:K\to\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ such that $f^{-1}(\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}))$ is a given finite subgroup of $K$.

Comment: Should the [representation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417436/is-every-finite-subgroup-the-integer-points-of-a-linear-algebraic-group#comment1071306_417436) be faithful, or is merely requiring it to be continuous enough?  (Of course one *could* ask either question, but I'm not sure which is more likely to be a faithful (har har) translation.)

Comment: @LSpice yes indeed, I should have written "faithful". Another tempting assumption is to assume it $\mathbf{Q}$-defined — this probably makes it closer to the intended meaning, but has the cost of using more language.

Comment: What's an example with $K$ of order $2$ and $G$ trivial?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie, do you really mean $K$ and $G$ as used in [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417436/is-every-finite-subgroup-the-integer-points-of-a-linear-algebraic-group#comment1071309_417436), rather than, perhaps, $K$ and $\Gamma$?  I think the question meant to assume $K$ connected.

Comment: While I'm guessing clarifications, I'm sure you also mean that there is an isomorphism $G(\mathbb R) \to K$ that carries $G(\mathbb Z)$ onto $\Gamma$, not just abstractly that $G(\mathbb R)$ is isomorphic to $K$ and $G(\mathbb Z)$ is (*via* a perhaps different isomorphism) isomorphic to $\Gamma$, right?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, sorry, I meant $K$ and $\Gamma$. I wondered whether we were meant to assume $K$ connected.

Comment: Wow this is a lot of comments I'll try to update my question make it clearer what I'm really interested in.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins : The icosahedral group cannot be got this way: the order of the finite group which satisfies the OP's condition divides 24.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question is no.
There exist finite groups $\Gamma \subset K$ of a compact connected Lie group $K$, such that for any algebraic $\mathbb Q$-group $G$ with $G(\mathbb R)=K$, the finite group  $\Gamma $ cannot be a subgroup of $G(\mathbb Z)$:

We take $K=SU(2)$ and $\Gamma $ to be a Dihedral group of the form $(\mathbb Z/l\mathbb Z)\rtimes {\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$ where the nontrivial element of the group ${\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$ operates by $x\mapsto -x$ on ${\mathbb Z}/l{\mathbb Z}$. Here $l$ is a large prime.

Suppose $G$ is an algebraic group defined over $\mathbb Q$ such that $G({\mathbb R})=K$, and $\Gamma \subset G(\mathbb Z)$. Then for almost all primes $p$, $\Gamma $ injects into $G({\mathbb F}_p)=G(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$.  Moreover, for almost all primes $p$, the order of $G({\mathbb F}_p)$ is $(p^2-1)(p^2-p)/(p-1)=p(p^2-1)$. Further, $l$ divides this order since $\Gamma $ is a subgroup of $G({\mathbb F}_p)$.

Therefore, for almost all primes $p$, we have $p(p^2-1)\equiv 0 \quad (mod \quad l)$. But by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, the residue class of the generator of the unit group of ${\mathbb Z}/l{\mathbb Z}$ is represented by infinitely many primes $p$. Hence the order of such a $p$ (modulo $l$) is $l-1$. On the other hand $p(p^2-1)$ is divisible by $l$ which means that $l-1\leq 2$, and $l$ cannot be a large prime.

I am pretty sure that a much simpler proof can be found, but  this is "a proof".

ADDED later: The proof shows that the "large prime" $l$ need only  satisfy $l\geq 5$. Moreover, the gcd of the numbers $p(p^2-1)$ as $p$ varies over primes large enough, is just $24$. Hence the order of $\Gamma $ is $\leq 24$.

Comment: What necessary condition does this give for a finite group to be the integer points of an algebraic $ \mathbb{Q} $ group? That is, what about the subgroup $ \Gamma $ do you use in this proof other than that it has order $ 2 \ell $ for some large prime $ \ell $? Also small note $ K=SU_2 $ doesn't contain dihedral subgroups or even any nonabelian groups of order $ 2 \ell $ for $ \ell $ prime. I suppose you wanted to take $ K=SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $. Or your proof probably would work with the order $ 4 \ell $ dicyclic subgroups of $ SU_2 $.

Comment: The diagonal subgroup of SU(2) contains $\mathbb Z/l\mathbb Z$, and the Weyl group element gives the extra Z/2Z$. So, the Dihedral group is indeed contained in SU(2).

Comment: I cannot offhand, think of a condition, but the order of $\Gamma$ should divide the gcd of $p(p^2-1)$ for all but finitely many $p$.

Comment: you are right of course, $ SU_2 $ contains $ O_2(\mathbb{R}) $ so certainly contains dihedral subgroups, I was a bit hasty on that one sorry.

Comment: This is probably another silly question but is there a reason that you use the dihedral group instead of just a cyclic group of prime order $ \ell $?

Comment: now that you mention it, no! I was thinking of irreducible finite subgroups of $SU(2)$ and hence thought of the dihedral group.

Comment: ah ok ok . So your proof shows that no finite groups of prime order can occur as integer points. And also order $ 2 \ell $ for $ \ell $ a large prime. Does your proof work for all groups of order $ pq $ for $ p,q $ distinct primes?

Comment: So does your edit imply we can take $\Gamma$ to be any dihedral subgroup of order 10? These can be given rather explicitly in terms of quaternions, which would be nice...

Comment: Yes. As Teixira remarked, you can even  take $\Gamma $ to be cyclic of order 5.

Comment: Thanks again for the great answer. Just wanted to point out that your claim about the existence of dihedral subgroups of $ SU_2 $ is wrong. My comment about the existence of an $ O_2 $ subgroup of $ SU_2 $ is also wrong. In fact my original claim that there are non dihedral subgroups of $ SU_2 $ (and thus no $ O_2 $ subgroups) is correct. To see this observe that the only element of $ SU_2 $ with order $ 2 $ is the diagonal  matrix with eigenvalues $ -1,-1 $. On the other hand the dihedral group $ D_{2n} $ has $ n $ elements of order $ 2 $ and $ O_2 $ has infinitely many order $ 2 $ elements.

Comment: Thanks again for the great answer. Just wanted to point out that your claim about the existence of dihedral subgroups of $ SU_2 $ is wrong. My comment about the existence of an $ O_2$ subgroup of $SU_2$ is also wrong. In fact my original claim that there do not exist any dihedral subgroups of $SU_2$ (and thus no $O_2$ subgroups either) is correct. To see this observe that the only element of $SU_2$ with order 2 is the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues −1,−1. On the other hand the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ has n elements of order 2 and $O_2$ has infinitely many elements of order $ 2 $.

Comment: In particular, the subgroup of  $SU_2 $ I thought was $ O_2 $ is actually best thought of as a sort of infinite dicyclic group. It is generated by the $ U_1 $ subgroup $ diag(e^{i\theta}, e^{-i \theta}) $ together with the order $ 4 $ element $ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \in SU_2 $.  On the other hand $ O_2 $ is generated (as a subgroup of $ U_2 $) by that same $ U_1 $ subgroup  $ diag(e^{i\theta}, e^{-i \theta}) $ together with the order 2 element $ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \in U_2 $ with determinant $ -1 $.